# Does CruiseControl.NET run on IIS 7.0?

Tags: iis-7, cruisecontrol.net

I'm new to development (an admin by trade) and I'm setting up my development environment and I would like to set up a CruiseControl.Net server on Server 2008.  A quick Google did not turn up any instructions for getting it running on IIS 7.0, so I was wondering if anyone had experience getting this set up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What Dale Ragan said; it installed flawlessly on our Windows Server 2008 machine, including the Dashboard running on IIS 7. Just give it a shot; should work fine.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a helpful article that worked for me:

[Getting CruiseControl.NET working under IIS7](http://huntjason.wordpress.com/2009/08/13/getting-cruisecontrol-net-working-under-iis7/)

Answer (score 3):

I have never tried on Server 2008, but I have installed CruiseControl.NET on Vista which includes IIS 7.0.  I don't remember there being any problems.  You do have an admin background which should help if something does pop up.

Just use the [CruiseControl.NET wiki](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Welcome+to+CruiseControl.NET) to get you thru the install and getting it setup.  That is all I did.

Comment: I also installed under Vista with IIS 7. Almost no problems. However, I had to adjust some user rights/privileges and on virtual directory folders and IIS' authentication method after the CC.NET setup had finished, then it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I got it running by following the steps in [this blog](http://www.matthewbussa.com/2011/05/installing-and-configuring-cruise.html). Additionally, I had to enable ASP.NET, as shown in [this blog](http://lamiavitaintrycatch.wordpress.com/2008/05/20/http-error-50019-iis-70-thoubles-fixed/). Lastly, to get the package install working, I gave full permission to the local users on the webdashboard directory, as in [this bug report](http://jira.public.thoughtworks.org/browse/CCNET-1664).